# How is this Minesweeper position possible?

Tags: minesweeper

[image: screenshot of Minesweeper board]

First of all, sorry for the bad quality of the picture.
Now guys seriously what's wrong here! I started playing Minesweeper a few days ago; it's a good game and all, but just check the picture:

- the 2 I had the mouse on has 3 mines around it.
- the 3 above it has 4 mines around it.
- the other 3 on the left of it also has 4 mines.
- the 1 on the left of the last 3 has 2 mines.

Now how is that possible? I really don't get it!
I would really appreciate someone to explain.
Thanks.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Questions here aren't required to be puzzles. The OP is asking about a problem they experienced while trying to solve a puzzle, so this is on-topic.

Comment: @IanMacDonald There are many types of perfectly valid but also mass-producible questions. It's on-topic for someone to post a Sudoku they've got stuck on and ask for help - that's what Stack Exchange is for, helping people with their problems. If someone posted a hundred of them, mods might take action against them; or if everyone started posting them all the time, we might have to consider some sort of measures against such puzzles; but these things aren't problems at the moment, so why worry about them?

Comment: I think you may have misread the puzzle. There are only 2 bombs adjacent to the 2.

Answer (score 13):

The crossed bomb corresponds to a square where a flag had been placed while no bomb was on it. Therefore it is not actually a bomb and this solves the problem.